# Find the Context Free Grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Let $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$. For each of the following languages, find a grammar that generates it.

(a) $L_1 = \{a^n b^m : n\geq 0, m>n\}$

(b) $L_1^3$

(C) $L_1^*$

I know the grammar for the language $L_1$, that is

$S \rightarrow aSb \mid bA$
$A \rightarrow bA \mid \epsilon$

please help me to find the grammars for another two languages.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post! As for b,c: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b) Introduce a new start symbol $S_1$ and a new production rule $S_1 \rightarrow SSS$

c) Introduce a new start symbol $S_2$ and a new production rule $S_2 \rightarrow S_2S \mid \epsilon$

Comment: Can I write $L1^3$ as $L1^3$ = {$a^nb^m a^p b^q a^r b^s : n, p, r >=0, m>n, q>p, s>r$} ?

how to write L1*?

Comment: @ManuThakur yes you can.

Comment: please tell me how to write L1*?

Comment: Just **[Kleene closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) of $L_1$**